# Cannot find module in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, npm, bootstrap-modal

hy guys i have problem like this,

i have a app.typescript
and inside it i import

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common'; 
import { MODAL_DIRECTVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'my-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my-app.component.css'],
  directives: [MODAL_DIRECTVES]
})
export class my-appComponent {
  title = 'Mp App';
}
```

but when i run it i got an error that say cant find module ng2-bootstrap

Comment: have you installed `ng2-bootstrap`

Comment: yes im using npm install ng2-bootstrap --save

Comment: `my-appComponent` isn't a valid class name, so could you revise your question to reflect an actual issue repro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/components/modal). It appears you must import from a nested path:

```js
import { MODAL_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
```

or

```js
import { MODAL_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/modal';
```